# How do I get continuous motion of ball?

Tags: android

This is my implementation of movement right now:

```
 public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    switch (event.getAction()) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
        move_ball=true;
        check_collisions();
        x+=speed_x;
        y+=speed_y;
        invalidate();

        Log.d("down", String.valueOf(x)+" "+String.valueOf(y));

        break;
    }



    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        move_ball=false;
        Log.d("up", String.valueOf(x)+" "+String.valueOf(y));


        break;
    }
return true;



};
```

But what I want is as long as the user has his finger on the screen the ball keeps moving as above while right now I need to keep moving my finger to obtain the movement.

Comment: What's wrong with MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN? Besides, if g is your canvas, then you are doing it wrong. You draw only in onDraw() and call invalidate() if you want to redraw...except for SurfaceView, but even then you'd be doing it wrong.

Comment: So how do i do it right?

Comment: Put all your drawing stuff in onDraw(), calculate your balls coordinates in onTouch() and call invalidate() to have onDraw() called. That's the way it works. And use ACTION_DOWN instead of ACTION_MOVE...

Comment: Thanks. The ball moves only when my finger is moving on the screen but when its still the ball stops. How do i make it move when the finger is still?

Comment: Read my comments again. I wrote it twice already.

Comment: @ElDuderino I updated the code. Is that what you mean? I apologize for the noobness.

Comment: Hey no problem :) and it still doesn't work? Are you using a normal View or a SurfaceView?

Comment: I'm using a Normal View

Comment: Ok, I found the problem. Check out my answer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a fully working example with a surfaceView. See how I did it, you have to grab the touch coordinates once and then move your ball there in an update method. Change the update method to change the balls movement.

```
public class BallView extends SurfaceView implements Runnable, SurfaceHolder.Callback {

private float ballX;
private float ballY;

private float touchX;
private float touchY;

private Paint ballPaint,backgroundPaint;
private ExecutorService service;

public BallView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    getHolder().addCallback(this);
    ballPaint = new Paint();
    ballPaint.setColor(Color.RED);
    backgroundPaint = new Paint();
    backgroundPaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
}

public void update() {
    float deltaX = touchX - ballX;
    float deltaY = touchY - ballY;

    ballX+=deltaX/100;
    ballY+=deltaY/100;

}

public void doDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.drawPaint(backgroundPaint);
    canvas.drawCircle(ballX, ballY, 100, ballPaint);
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    Log.i("Touch","Event");
    if(event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
        touchX = event.getX();
        touchY = event.getY();
    }       
    return true;
}

private boolean running;
@Override
public void run() {
    running = true;
    while(running) {

        update();

        Canvas canvas = getHolder().lockCanvas();
        if(canvas!=null) {

            doDraw(canvas);

            getHolder().unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);

        }

    }
}

@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    if(service == null) service = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
    service.execute(this);
}

@Override
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width,
        int height) {

}

@Override
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    running = false;
}

}
```

MainActivity

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setContentView(new BallView(this));
}
```